# Query usage metadata from Teradata

Tags: teradata

I need to extract the metadata for the query executions for the last month in Teradata for a given database.
For example, how much MB is the most performance expensive query ran, what is the average query cost in MB, and such.

Is this information even available, and If it is, which table holds it?

P.S. I'm using Teradata Vantage express for testing purposes on a virtual Linux machine, if that makes any difference.

I've been searching in the official documentation. Spend there a good amount of time, but find it pretty hard to find this information.
I see some people are using 'ResUsageSPMA_hst' table, which seems to be missing on my end.

Comment: SPMA is server node-level. For query-level metadata, you need Database Query Logging (DBQL) which at least for Vantage Express requires you to explicitly BEGIN QUERY LOGGING. Metadata is logged to DBC tables initially; best practice for a "real" system is to offload logs daily to "PDCR" _hst tables (which can be managed via Viewpoint) but for Vantage Express you typically leave the data in DBC for as long as you need it and then purge it to reclaim the space.

Comment: @Fred How to properly use BEGIN QUERY LOGGING and where the output goes? 
As per the "real" production systems, is this logging enabled by default?
Also is there a way to write a query which will work both on TD VE and on a real one without changing anything?

Comment: There's no DBQL by default, the DBA has to enable it. The captured data is stored in the dbc.DBQL* tables (QryLog* views). See https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Database-Administration/Tracking-Query-Behavior-with-Database-Query-Logging-Operational-DBAs